# Where to install python library or package

Tags: python, squish

Using squish tool to automate my application,

Need to know in which path python library should get installed.

Using Linux environment.

Also is there any possibility to add python library in squish IDE?

Comment: Your question could mean many things.  Python doesn't really use the term "library".  Are you asking where to install Python itself?  Are you asking where to install your own custom package?  Are you asking where to install a third-party package?

Answer (score 1):

**Changing to External Python Installation**

Squish ships with two Python versions, Python 2.x, Python 3.x.

If you want to use a standard package/module, or one that is to be installed in the Python installation, then the general recommendation is to install the same major and minor Python version as in your Squish installation, and then configure Squish to use this external Python installation. This is usually best done via the "PythonChanger.py" provided by the vendor. This knowledge base article explains this, and links to the PythonChanger.py file:

https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/changing-python-installation-used-squish-binary-packages/

**Installing Packages/Modules**

Afterwards you can install the desired packages/modules in that external Python installation, and that way have them available in the Squish Python test scripts/case/suites.

**Packages/Modules in Squish' Global Scripts**

If however, you want to have your package/module in a separate folder somewhere else, a good place may be inside a separate folder in the "Global Scripts" (see the view with this name in the Squish IDE).

**Packages/Modules in PyDev**

Also, keeping in mind that the Squish IDE's Python functionality is generally based on "PyDev", so instructions for configuring this in PyDev apply to the Squish IDE in general, too:

For adding to the packages/modules "search path" in general, see Edit > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter, then Libraries.

**Packages/Modules per project (Squish Test Suite) in PyDev**

For adding to the packages/modules "search path" for a specific test suite, open the "PyDev Package Explorer" view (Window > Show View... > Other... > PyDev), right click on the desired test suite and choose Properties, then see PyDev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries.